# Angular front-end not updating instantly

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using Angular as front-end and express as server. I am passing new object from front-end (Angular) to server (express) via http.

angular file:

```
 this.issuesService.addIssue(newIssue).subscribe(); //after adding that navigating to issues link where it displays all the issues
 this.router.navigate(["/issues"]);
```

When I am listing all the issues, it's not updated at the first time.
But it's there when I am refreshing or visiting that link again.

express file:

```
  router.post('/addIssue', (req, res) => {
    ...
   newIssue = req.body...//
   issues.push(newIssue);//that new issue successfully added - no problem here
  });
```

How to make that update (displaying list instantly when express got updated) dynamically?

Comment: You should consider returning at least a 200 status code from your express route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably because you are redirecting the user to `/issues` before the HTTP call has finished.

```
this.issuesService.addIssue(newIssue)
    .subscribe(() => 
       this.router.navigate(["/issues"]);   
    );
```

The `addIssue` method take some time(async) and `this.router.navigate(["/issues"]);` will happen instant (sync).

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, also `this.router.navigate(["/issues"]);` is asynchronous but will happen faster than the HTTP call. Basically is a Promise that you can wait to be resolved and so something (not necessarily needed in your code).

Good luck!

Comment: a better way would be to use angular resolver so that the request is run when user navigate (or is redirected) to issue route but that is just optimization